# LibreWolf browser unable to remember view settings

Tags: gnome, browser, nixos

I'm using `NixOS` version `23.05.885.bb8b5735d6f` under `GNOME`. I installed `LibreWolf` — using `Flatpak`. The problem I'm facing is that any time I open any site and set the zoom level, for instance, to 120 %, when I open a new tab (with the same site) I would expect the same settings to be maintained. What currently happens is that the zoom level is reset on every single tab, so it looks like I'm opening a brand new site for every tab.

I tested this on a new installation; also with and without the usual extensions I have installed.

Anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone runs into the same situation, disabling `Enable ResistFingerprinting` did it for me:

[image]

I ended up using the `CanvasBlocker` extension, as suggested by `LibreWolf` as well.